# How to do custom view controller transitions with reusing views

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've been playing with the new view controller transition APIs introduced in iOS 7 for quite a while now.

I achieved a lot of cool results, it's a really, really good API. Though, all of the things I did were basically transitions from one screen to another. No content ever changed in those screens but the container view's origin.

I want to achieve an effect like the Tweetbot photo viewer, where you tap on a view and the view that you tapped gets moved to another view, which is managed by a completely different view controller.

What's the best way of doing this? I can think of some hacky things, so I thought I'd get some opinions before I implemented it.

Cheers!